# What are the dates on these documents?

Tags: 19th-century, palaeography, date

[This document](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:3QS7-99QD-ZTNW?i=1416&wc=M79W-ZNG%3A344538501%2C346625801%3Fcc%3D2036959&cc=2036959) from a Mississippi probate record has what appears to be a date at the top:
[image]

Later on the page, I see:
[image]

[The following page](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:3QS7-L9QD-ZYJL?i=1417&wc=M79W-ZNG%3A344538501%2C346625801%3Fcc%3D2036959&cc=2036959) shows this date:

[image]

What are these dates? Is what looks to me like "96" really supposed to be "9th"?

Comment: Can you glean more data from nearby documents?

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by Jan, I looked at adjacent documents, where I found this:
[image]

That seems to answer my question: The date is January 9, 1879. What looks like a "6" is really "th" (or the equivalent).